# How do I properly change the value of a prefab'd instance variable?

Tags: unity, c#

I am currently following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEaU_mcYsRM&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR42oVBU6K2DIL6Y22Ry9J1c&index=36) on how to make a 2D platformer in Unity.

The tutorial explains how to make an enemy wave spawner, but it doesn't explain how to make enemies stronger after I have completed a certain amount of waves.

So, to explain: I have an `Enemy` class, which has an `EnemyStats` class in it:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class EnemyStats
    {
        public int damage = 20;
        public int maxHealth = 100;

        public int CurrentHealth
        {
            get { return _currentHealth; }
            set { _currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, maxHealth); }
        }

        private int _currentHealth;

        public void Init()
        {
            CurrentHealth = maxHealth;
        }
    }

    public EnemyStats stats = new EnemyStats();

    private StatusIndicator statusIndicator;

    void Awake()
    {
        stats.Init();
        statusIndicator = transform.Find("StatusIndicator").GetComponent<StatusIndicator>();

        if (statusIndicator != null)
        {
            statusIndicator.SetHealth(stats.CurrentHealth, stats.maxHealth);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `WaveSpawner` class I have the method to spawn the enemy:

```
private void SpawnEnemy(Enemy enemy)
{
    Transform sp = spawnPoints[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)];

    if (CurrentWave % 5 == 0)
    {
        enemy.stats.maxHealth += 20;
    }

    Instantiate(enemy.transform, sp.position, sp.rotation);
}
```

In the `WaveSpawner` you can set a certain number of waves (let's say 5), and after you complete all of the waves I've set them to repeat.
So after I beat the 5 waves, I want the 5 waves to repeat and the enemies to be stronger (for example to have their max hp increased by 20).

I do that with the line: `enemy.stats.maxHealth += 20;`

But the problem here is that after this line is executed and I `Instantiate` the enemy `prefab`, the `prefab` changes its value in the inspector. So let's say that the initial value of the `prefab` was 120, after I beat the 5 enemy waves, the value of the `prefab` is set to 140. Then, after I reset the game, the initial value of the `prefab` is 140 and the max health of the first enemies is 140 and not 120.

I have tried to not change the `maxHealth` variable of the `EnemyStats` class, but instead to have another variable `tempMaxHealth` and do the changes on it. This doesn't resolve my problem, as other problems arise and I don't know what to do anymore.

I hope that you have an answer for me, I would be grateful if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, the variable called `enemy` here is your *prefab*.

Sometimes I'll name these variables something like `enemyPrefab` so I can't lose track of what's a source asset I shouldn't modify at runtime, versus what's a dynamic instance.

When we write it this way it's obvious:

```
if (CurrentWave % 5 == 0) {
    enemyPrefab.stats.maxHealth += 20;
}
```

We just changed the prefab with this line, so it's natural that we see it change in the inspector.

Instead we should do something like this - we capture *the instance of the enemy prefab that we just spawned* and modify *that*:

```
Enemy enemyInstance = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, sp.position, sp.rotation);

int numHealthBoosts = CurrentWave/5;
enemyInstance.stats.maxHealth += numHealthBoosts * 20;
```

Any code that works with the maxHealth should be moved from `Awake`/`OnEnable` (which run before `Instantiate` returns) and into `Start` or a custom initializer method so it runs after our spawning routine finishes and sees the updated value of the stats.

Comment: The only thing I should point out here (for everyone who'll face the same issue) is that the `Instantiate` method returns a `Transform` type, and you cannot cast a `Transform` into an `Enemy` class (in my case). I mean this line: `Enemy enemyInstance = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, sp.position, sp.rotation);`. But what I did was to get the component from the instantiated `Transform`: `var stats = enemyInstance.GetComponent<Enemy>().stats`. Apart from that, everything's fine and it finally works. Thank you.

Comment: The generic form of Instantiate returns whatever type you pass it, so make sure to pass an Enemy type and you'll get an Enemy out, no GetComponent required.

Comment: You are right, once again. I apologize for not noticing it.